# Keyboard and Mouse working issue

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I own a Dell 5500 Series laptop and I have Windows 10 operating system. Recently I bought a Dell wireless keyboard and mouse and after a month of using it I started to face keyboard and mouse Malfunctioning issue.

These are few things that I have been facing for some time now:-

1. The scroller of mouse starts increasing and decreasing the icon size of folders in desktop and folders instead of scrolling up and down.
2. The keyboard alphabet keys stops working on wireless and laptop keyboard. Few keys still work like backlight and screen light keys, spacebar and backspace but left control and shift doesn't work too.
3. When I click on any folder and try to open other folder it starts to open in new window instead of opening in the same window.
4. Same happens in the browser, mouse scoller increases the size of page instead of scrolling down the page. And left key open each link into new tab instead of opening in the same page.

I have tried many solutions, restarted it many times, tried to uninstall and update the driver of both the keyboards, tried "ease of access" but couldn't get it right.

If anyone have any solution please let me know or have faced this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a stuck CTRL key. An online keyboard tester would show that.

Answer (score 0):

Given all you have tried and both keyboards are not working correctly, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

I suggest this because you have tried drivers and Keyboard, Mouse are foundational to the operating system.

If, for whatever reason, a Repair Install does not work, backup your system and reinstall Windows.